# Android adb Logcat going crazy with some devices connected

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, logcat

I'm using **Eclipse** since long time for Android developing and the adb **logcat** works always fine with most devices.
With some tablet, when I connect the device the 'All messages (no filters)' run very fast and the messages in filters disappear too fast, even when the application is almost sleeping... So I can't ready anything.
I really can't understand how this can happen.

Comment: Well, if you just catch EVERYTHING it'll generate around 1 mb of data per second. In pure log text. I switched to android studio myself, which already filters out a lot of the not-application specific logging stuff but you should be able to set several pages with different filters in eclipse too, to see which kinds of events are happening when.

Comment: Assuming you have debugging output enabled of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you set your logcat to **'All messages (no filters)'** it will simply catch every kind of event that is going on with your application **and** your Android tablet.

You must add your `project package-name` as a filter in order to receive only log events about the app you're developing.

Comment: the package name is added, and other filters are added... the question is that for a strange reason the log runs fast, and all messages in the filter disappear too...

Comment: Are you sure you're watching Logcat instead of Logcat (deprecated) ?

Comment: I'm always using Logcat. It's possible that Logcat (deprecated) is activated only for some devices ?

Comment: Can you please update your answer with a screenshot of your working eclipse?